# How to use image in Webp in inside of data-background (from bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webp

I'm using bootstrap with a background image in a section, I wanna change img/bg4.jpg for bg4.webp, but I don't know how to use webp in this case, since I am not using data-background instead of  or css condition.

```
<section class="bg-img bg-fixed" data-background="img/bg4.jpg">
```

....